# Using a variable string in a select * from statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Is something like this possible?:

```
DECLARE @test nvarchar(30) = 'Appt'

SELECT * FROM @test.dbo.tablename with (NOLOCK)
```

or possibly

```
DECLARE @test nvarchar(30) = 'Appt'

SELECT * FROM @test + '.dbo.tablename' with (NOLOCK)
```

No, right?

I'm not looking to put the whole string into a variable and then use "EXEC." I have long scripts that I want to just try to replace that with when it occurs.

Thank you.

Comment: no. not possible. you need to build a string and then exec it.

Comment: Ok, That's what I thought. Was just being hopeful :(

Comment: But what is the problem? You can create a function `DoQuery(@test)` and encapsulate the `EXEC` call

Comment: Often, it's easier to take your existing long script, add in placeholders for whatever you want to replace, and then call `replace` on those strings to fill in any values than to dynamically assemble the whole thing.  It sounds like your concern is primarily with ease of development/ maintenance.  If you have a string `select * from ##dbname##.dbo.tablename with (nolock)`, you can do `replace(your_string, '##dbname##, 'Appt')` and then execute that.  If you are just replacing database names, maybe you just need `sp_MSforeachDB`.

Comment: You might require to go for Dynamic sql

Comment: so, @JustinCave, would that mean id have to do: **_SELECT * FROM ApptDEMO.dbo.Table with (NOLOCK)_** and **_SELECT REPLACE('ApptDemo.dbo.Table', 'ApptDemo', 'Appt')_**?

Comment: You'd still need to use dynamic SQL.  It's just that your code is cleaner if you `declare @sqlStmt = 'select * from ##dbname##.dbo.Table with (nolock)`; set @sqlStmt = replace( @sqlStmt, '##dbname##', 'Appt' ); exec @sqlStmt` rather than assembling the entire SQL statement in code particularly when you have a lot of code and a lot of places where you want to do the same replacement (i.e. '##dbname##' appears in a number of places in your code).

Comment: Slight detour...but one you need. You should not litter your database with NOLOCK hints. It is far more sinister than most people think. It can and will return missing and/or duplicate rows. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Answer (score 2):

This requires Dynamic SQL. Basically you create a string that builds the SQL statement dynamically based on your query. That string is then executed with an EXEC Statement. A basic example is like this:

```
DECLARE @test nvarchar(30) = 'Appt'
DECLARE @sql as varchar(max)
SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM' +  @test + '.dbo.tablename' + 'with (NOLOCK)'
EXEC @SQL
```

Assuming your tablename was `Appt.dbo.tablename`

I think you meant:

```
SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM' +  'dbo.' + @test + ' with (NOLOCK)'
```

Comment: Well the problem is that i have many many insert statements and select statements. so i cant put them all into a variable.

Comment: You can write your heart away. You simply use `SELECT` statements and concatenation to create the whole statement and exec at the end. Don't forget scope. Its more challenging to create a variable within the dynamic SQL. Also keep in mind when you execute a statement:
`SELECT * FROM ABCD`  `INSERT INTO dbo.Something`...

That will execute together even if there are no spaces.

Comment: The statements in your question are open to SQL Injection Attacks. Always use [QUOTENAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/ms176114.aspx) for table names when building dynamic SQL to avoid such attacks. Like `SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM' +  'dbo.' + QUOTENAME(@test) + ' with (NOLOCK)'`. Also: `EXEC (@SQL);` (cf https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Nice explanation logixologist.

Because Tom wants to run it for multiple select statements, i was thinking he could store all the table names in a column and use a cursor to fetch the table values. Considering you would create a table first such as:

```
CREATE TABLE tableName ( name varchar(20));
```

then run the following code once you inserted the right values in the table above.

```
Declare @table VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @sql as varchar(max)
SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM' +  'dbo.' + @table + ' with (NOLOCK)'

DECLARE table_cursor CURSOR FOR 
select distinct([name]) FROM DBname.dbo.tableName
Where [name] is not null

OPEN table_cursor
FETCH Next from table_cursor 
INTO @table
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS =0
BEGIN

EXEC @SQL

FETCH NEXT FROM table_cursor
INTO @table
END
CLOSE table_cursor
DEALLOCATE table_cursor
```

The cursor would return the table name for the select statement. I think you could use the same logic for insert statements.

Comment: Most DBA's would get heartburn if you even mentioned using a Cursor to create Dynamic SQL. It might work but its less maintainable if you run into an issue. Harder to figure out where the problem is.